Supabase email changing time, why I am getting double email?
 const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
      email: form.newEmail,
    });

I am using nextjs and I have tried many ways, but getting two mail address on both , new and old addresses.
but another problem is if I click "change email" from old mail address . then it's not working!
but from new email adress mail box, if I click. then it's working!
why ?
I want only one mail

see the first answer. (sorry)

Sorry!actually I investigate it, it's send confirm mail both address because of security. so both email address when confirm.. no matter when, then automatically email will be change –

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
